# One-to-one property in EF 6 does not update.

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Code First.

Model:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public Language PreferredLang { get; set; }
    //more properties
}
```

`UserProfile` table is generated with `PreferredLang_LanguageID` column. I wrote following method to save user profile. If this UserID is found in DB, I update, otherwise I add row.

```
public static void UpdateProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
{
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        if (db.UserProfiles.Any(p => p.UserID == userProfile.UserID))
        {
            //does not save language properly
            db.UserProfiles.Attach(userProfile);
            db.Entry(userProfile).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(userProfile.PreferredLang).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            //duplicates language
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There are two problems.

1. When I create new UserProfile (db.UserProfiles.Add), new entry for Language is created, even though Language already existed. PreferredLanguage had ID = 2, and after `db.SaveChanges`, it created new Language with ID = 5 (smallest available) and set `PreferredLang_LanguageID = 5`. **How can I use existing Language?**
2. When I update existing UserProfile, then all properties (columns) are updated in DB, except for `` `PreferredLang_LanguageID ``. This one stays the same. **How could Language be updated?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is not the most elegant solution, but it's the only one that worked for me. If existing entry is found, then it is removed and new instance is attached to context:

```
if (db.UserProfiles.Any(p => p.UserID == userProfile.UserID))
{
     //not elegant, but only solution that works                   
     db.UserProfiles.Remove(db.UserProfiles.Find(userProfile.UserID));
}
db.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
db.Languages.Attach(userProfile.PreferredLang);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer first part of question - saving without creating new entry for Language. I attached `PreferredLang`:

```
{
     db.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
     db.Languages.Attach(userProfile.PreferredLang);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```